# Applying degree 2 or 3 irreducibility tests to higher degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-rings

> Given the polynomial$\ x^4+x+1$, I have to find out if it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q $.

When looking at the solutions, they applied the degree 2 or 3 irreducibly tests to determine that it was irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.
Similarly, they also applied it to the polynomial $x^5+5x^2+1$.
Can someone explain why this is allowed?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean degree 2 or 3 irreducibility test? I suspect that it may be about testing for the presence/absence of rational zeros. This is insufficient for degrees higher than 3. The standard example is $(x^2+1)^2$. José Carlos Santos offers another nice test (works for quartics). I would have done both of your examples by proving that they both remain irreducible after reduction modulo two, but that is just me :-)

Comment: It seems I was mistaken about the degree 2/3 irreducibility tests part. They did what you suggested, the reduction modulo two. However, I am still confused on this part. They stated that f(0) = 1 and f(1) = 1 so f(x) is irreducible over Z2. How does the fact that the polynomial has no zeroes in Z2 tell us that it is irreducible without the degree 2 or 3 irreducibility test?

Comment: They must have also checked that it was not divisible (modulo two) by the **only** quadratic irreducible $x^2+x+1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$. Because you have then tested the polynomial agains all linear and quadratic factors you are good up to degree five.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^4+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. That can be proved using [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Factoring_quartic_polynomials): one first considers the resolvent cubic of $x^4+x+1$, which is is $x^3-4x-1$. Does it have rational roots? No. Therefore,  $x^4+x+1$ is irreducible.

However, the method used for determining whether a quadritic or cubic polynomial is irreducible (determining whether it has a rational root) doesn't work for higher degrees.